# Objective C, SQLite, Error while creating update statement. not an error

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, sql-update

This is the first time I came around UPDATE statement in SQLITE. Base on what I found, I came up with this method that, well, does not work) The statement itself works fine, I have checked it. And values of result and SQLITE_OK equals to 0 for some reason. So, where did it went wrong? Thank you.

```
- (BOOL) archiveArticle:(Article *) article
{
    NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE UserArticle SET archived = ? WHERE article_id=? AND user_id=?"];

    sqlite3_stmt *update;
    int result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(self.db, [sql UTF8String], -1, &update, NULL);
    NSLog(@"archiveArticle: Before IF %d %d",result, SQLITE_OK);
    if (result == SQLITE_OK){
        NSLog(@"archiveArticle: Article was archived!");
        return true;
    }else{
        NSLog(@"archiveArticle: Error while creating update statement. %s", sqlite3_errmsg(self.db));
        return false;
    }
    sqlite3_bind_int(update, 1, 1);

    sqlite3_bind_int(update, 2 , article.article_id);

    sqlite3_bind_int(update, 3 , 16);


    char* errmsg;
    sqlite3_exec(self.db, "COMMIT", NULL, NULL, &errmsg);

    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(update))
        NSLog(@"Error while updating. %s", sqlite3_errmsg(self.db));

    sqlite3_finalize(update);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is with this portion of code:

```
if (result == SQLITE_OK){
        NSLog(@"archiveArticle: Article was archived!");
        return true;
    }else{
        NSLog(@"archiveArticle: Error while creating update statement. %s", sqlite3_errmsg(self.db));
        return false;
    }
```

You are returning from the method, so the remaining code won't be executed. So the

```
sqlite3_exec(self.db, "COMMIT", NULL, NULL, &errmsg);
```

won't work and data won't be updated.

Comment: Oh, of course. I attempt to do something after I return. How stupid of me)) Thank you very much :)